# Pulling information from a .txt file in python based on a user input

Tags: python, input

I have a list in the form of a .txt file that i need to pull certain information from based on a user input.

```
Latitude   Longitude  City  Province/State   Country
82°30N     62°20W     Alert Nunavut    Canada
81°36N     16°40W     Nord  Greenland  Denmark
79°59N     85°56W     Eureka     Nunavut    Canada
```

this is a snippet of the list. I understand how to pull the information out and put it into a list. I need to find the city that the user inputs and then output the linked lat and lon of the city. I am new to python so not sure what process i could use to solve this.

Comment: Is every entry on one line, and is every field guaranteed to be separated by a space?

Comment: yes, each entry has its own line and they are separated by a tab('\t')

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting it into a list I would put the output into a `pandas.Dataframe` (or just a `dict`). Assuming your text-file is separated with tabs, has a header and each row is of equal length, you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',delimiter='\t')

print('Enter name of City:')
name = input()
print('Latitude:', df[df['City'] == name]['Latitude'].values, 'Longitude:', df[df['City'] == name]['Longitude'].values)
```

If you execute the script and type the city name it will be stored as a string into `name`. After that we print the Long/Lat values selecting the corresponding city from the `DataFrame`.

Comment: That works but i'm not allowed to use modules in this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

simple pythonic way, hope it may help you

```
city = input("Enter City name")

with open('your text file') as file:
    print(file.readline().split()[:3])
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.split()[2] == city:
            print(line.split()[:3])
```